# Limit involving Riemann xi function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I am trying the evaluate the following limit $$\lim_{r\to 1^-}\frac{\xi'\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right)}{(1-r)\ \xi\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right)} $$
where $\xi$ denotes the Riemann xi function.

Let $$L=\lim_{r\to 1^-}\frac{\xi'\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right)}{(1-r)\ \xi\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right)} $$
Since the above limit is of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ so using L'Hôpital's rule
we get $$L=\lim_{r\to 1^-}\frac{\xi''\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right).\frac{1}{(1-r)^2}}{\frac{1}{(1-r)}.\xi'\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right)-\xi\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right)} $$
So on simplification we get $$L=\lim_{r\to 1^-}\frac{\xi''\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right).\frac{1}{(1-r)}}{\xi'\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right)-(1-r)\ \xi\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right)} $$
Can we evaluate this limit using sage math? I am struggling to find this limit. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn’t this just the limit of $x\xi’(x)/\xi(x)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @Aphelli Yes but what is the value of that limit?

Comment: @Aphelli Yes you are right. But how to evaluate limit of $x\xi'(x)/\xi(x)$ as $x\to \infty$?

Comment: This expression equals $x(\zeta’/\zeta)(x)+(2x-1)/(x-1)-x\frac{\ln{\pi}}{2}+\frac{x}{2}(\Gamma’/\Gamma)(x/2)$. The first term is easily shown negligible, the second is converging, the third one is linear. All that remains for you to do is study the last term. Hint: if $\psi=\Gamma’/\Gamma$, find a functional equation satisfied by $\psi$.

Comment: @Aphelli Thank you. But how do we study the third term. Please write a brief answer. I will accept it.

Comment: What have you tried?